# Can ‘haben’ and ‘sein’ be used somewhat interchangeably for adjectives?

Tags: meaning, verb-usage

> Ich bin groß — I am tall.
>   Ich habe Hunger — I am hungry

How come *haben* has got the meaning *am* here?

Does the second line really mean *I am hungry* or *I have hunger*?

Comment: Do you see a different meaning in your both, last examples in the last sentence?

Comment: There are a couple of more adjectives, that are connected with somatic sensations that can be constructed the same way. "Einen Durst haben" means to be thirsty. It is also possible to say "durstig sein" but that is uncommon. In the south (Austria Bavaria) they also say "Einen Schlaf haben" instead of "müde sein" for beeing sleepy.

Comment: Voting to reopen. The two questions approach the problem from different angles and thus are not duplicates of another. This one presumes that ‘Ich habe Hunger’ were a direct translation of ‘I am hungry’.

Comment: @Beta: *Einen Durst haben* ist aber ein Regionalismus und daher hier off topic, denn ohne ausdrückliche Frage danach geht es hier immer um Standarddeutsch. *Durst haben* würde ich gelten lassen - dass es häufiger ist als *durstig sein* würde ich gerne belegt sehen, offensichtlich finde ich das nicht.

Comment: @userunknown Regionalismen sind off-topic, solange nicht explizit danach gefragt würde? Das sehe ich anders.

Comment: @Jan: Du stimmst aber zu, dass aus Betas Kommentar nicht hervorgeht, dass das kein Standarddeutsch ist, was er da unterrichtet und viele Anfänger/Fremdsprachler das nicht erkennen können?

Comment: @userunknown Es kann sich nur noch um »einen Durst haben« drehen, denn alles andere steht hinter »In the south they also say«; das ist klar genug. Andererseits können viele Deutsche auch nicht wirklich klar sagen, was Regionalismus und was Standarddeutsch ist. Jeder, der von klein auf *heuer* gesagt und gehört hat, wird das für den Standard halten; genauso wie ich davon ausgehe, dass wer »Wutz« von klein auf gehört hat, das ebenso tut. Und man wird dies – absichtlich oder unabsichtlich – auch gegenüber Fremdsprachlern tun. Mindestens deswegen sollten sie zumindest *erwähnt* werden.

Comment: Und meines Erachtens würde es noch viel mehr verwirren, wenn man zu dem Punkt kommt, an dem man Zeitungen lesen kann, und eine Samstagszeitung aus dem Norden plötzlich »Sonnabend« in ihrer Titelzeile hat.

Comment: @Jan: Gerade durch Mediengebrauch, Zeitungen, Fernsehen, Radio, Bücher lernt mal sehr bald regionalen Sprachgebrauch von Standarddeutsch zu unterscheiden. Niemand lebt in einer lokalen Sprachbubble. Ich wette Du findest keinen erwachsenen Österreicher, der nicht weiß, dass heuer bei Piefkes ungebräuchlich ist.

Comment: @userunknown [Gegenbeispiel](http://www.sueddeutsche.de/news?search=heuer&sort=date&all%5B%5D=dep&all%5B%5D=typ&all%5B%5D=sys&all%5B%5D=time).

Answer (score 7):

As you guessed, the literal translation of the second line would be "I have hunger", while "I am hungry" can also be translated as "Ich bin hungrig".

Both variants are correct and appropriate, although "Ich habe Hunger" seems to be far more used (judged just by my feeling). But I would be surprised if someone would even notice you saying "Ich bin hungrig."

Besides the fact that the first one conceptualizes *hunger* as something you can *have*, you can *possess* and the second one expresses a state of you being, I do not really see a difference in the two german expressions. (And this difference in conceptualisation is just the same in german as in english.)

Comment: which one is more appropriate, Ich habe hunger or Ich bin hungrig?

Comment: @InQusitive: I edited my answer to answer the question of your comment, too.

Comment: Where I come from people more often say "Ich bin hungrig".

Answer (score 3):

There is no German word *hunger* — only *Hunger* (note the capitalisation). *Hunger,* the German capitalised word, is a noun; not an adjective. Therefore, it is only logical that you *have* it as opposed to ‘being’ it. The direct translation of ‘Ich habe Hunger’ is indeed:

> I have hunger.

The corresponding adjective is *hungrig* and it takes *sein* as you would expect.

> Ich bin hungrig.

German is like English in this respect: If you are dealing with a predicative adjective, it must be joined to the subject by the copula *sein.* If you are talking about a state which is represented by a noun, you need *to have* or *haben.*

Comment: *Ich bin Schwimmer*. Schwimmer ist auch ein Hauptwort, kein Adjektiv. Ist es daher logisch, dass man Schwimmer hat, nicht ist?

Comment: @userunknown Guter Punkt. Mein erster Gedanke: Dabei handelt es sich ja um einen Gleichsetzungsnominativ, der »mich« (die sprechende/schreibende Person) mit dem Substantiv *Schwimmer* gleichsetzt. Ich bin aber nicht der Hunger (das wäre einer der vier apokalyptischen Reiter), ich habe ihn nur (den Zustand, an/in mir). Bin ich damit dem Einwand begegnet, d.h. kann ich das so in die Antwort einbauen, oder habe ich wieder nur einen Schritt zu kurz gedacht?

Comment: -1 since the answer is wrong and misleading.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Can you elaborate any more than the point user unknown has raised? I would love to know more about where I am wrong and misleading.

Comment: I just refer on the pount userunknown already has stated. To my eye you are supposed to give an answer which you are certain of. Answers shall be correct, If they aren't I downvote them.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Okay, I’m fine with that =) I was hoping on feedback from user unknown concerning my proposed extension before I edit to prevent multiple rounds of editing, though. That’s why I didn’t take action yet.